# Why does upload of an Excel file fail after changing from Windows 7 to Windows 10?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

We use an asp.net web application with file uploading code as it can be seen below.

```
else if (action == "import_excel")
{
    var excelFile = Request.Files["excelFile"];
    var path = "";
    try
    {
        string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(excelFile.FileName);
        string fileextension = Path.GetExtension(excelFile.FileName);
        var server = Server.MapPath("~");
        path = Path.Combine(server, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExcelFileDir"], excelFile.FileName);

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            path = Path.Combine(server, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExcelFileDir"], filename + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("mmddyyyyhh24mmss") + "" + fileextension);
            excelFile.SaveAs(path);
        }
        else
        {
            excelFile.SaveAs(path);
        }
        DataTable excelDT = new DataTable();

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection())
        {
            string Import_FileName = path;
            string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(Import_FileName);
            if (fileExtension == ".xls")
                conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Import_FileName + ";" + "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;'";
            if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
                conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Import_FileName + ";" + "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'";
            using (OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                comm.CommandText = "Select * from [rewards$]";
                comm.Connection = conn;
                using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                {
                    da.SelectCommand = comm;
                    da.Fill(excelDT);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (DataRow row in excelDT.Rows)
        {
            string emp_id = row["empid"].ToString();
            string added_pts = row["points"].ToString();
            string remarks = row["remarks"].ToString();

            int transID = global.NextIDValue("TRANSACTIONS");
            postTrans.PointsValue = Convert.ToInt32(added_pts);
            postTrans.TransID = transID;
            postTrans.EmpID = emp_id;
            postTrans.DateT = DateTime.Today.Date;
            postTrans.Remarks = remarks;
            employee.EmpID = emp_id;
            postTrans.TransClass = "Earn";
            postTrans.PointsPrev = Convert.ToInt32(employee.GetCurrPoints());
            postTrans.PointsCurr = int.Parse(employee.GetCurrPoints()) + int.Parse(added_pts);
            postTrans.Status = "Done";
            postTrans.InsertTransaction();
        }
        Admin.GenerateLogs("Executed Import Excel by: ");

        Response.Write("saved");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Admin.GenerateLogs("Failed Excel Import by: ");
        Response.Write("-invalid-");
    }
    Response.End();
}
```

The file uploading of Excel file worked fine before on Windows 7. But the file uploading part does not work anymore after changing operating system to Windows 10.

One more problem is that the file upload does also not work anymore when we return our OS back to Windows 7.

Can someone explain what happened in our web app?

Where is the cause of the problem? Is it on file upload code or on Windows OS?

Comment: Is the client changing between 7 and 10 or the server?  Do you see any kind of error during the upload?  Maybe try using this instead of Server.MapPath:  var server = AppContext.BaseDirectory;

Comment: all PC in here chage win 7 to win 10

Comment: so all clients, right?  This is hosted from a server OS that has not changed?  What about using different browsers... same results?

Comment: I have a feeling this might be a .NET version problem.  See this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed

Comment: When you said "web app" I assumed it was running in a browser, but seems like this might be a desktop app that connects to the server?  Embedded browser?

Comment: asp.net that is connected to a server

Comment: hey man, i knotice that the web app is only not accepting .xlsx and only accepts .xls extension when i try to upload file that is .xlsx its trows me an error like this The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. my question is if i install this microsoft.ace.oleb.12.0 is it gonna work

Comment: You might consider using NPOI: https://github.com/dotnetcore/NPOI

Comment: i figureout whats wrong.Theres nothing wrong in my project its working fine but in the server its not working the file uploading , all file extension .xls and .xlsx not working on server . but again its working before then suddenly  its not the chaging of OS version is nothing to deal with it, Do you have any idea why its happening ?

Comment: not sure... my methods are different... for instance I don't use file.SaveAs.   If you see any error messages, post those.  That would help people understand what the issue might be.

Comment: May be related?: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f59c1fbf-69a1-4733-89d1-62c068b4bdfd/oledb-not-working-in-windows-10-os?forum=csharpgeneral